# Al querer crear una llave foranea me dice identificador no valido?

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

**--CREACION DE LA TABLA Categ PRODUCTOS**

```
CREATE TABLE FCT_CATEG_PRODUCTOS (
    CATPR_ID NUMERIC(5,0) NOT NULL,
    CATPR_NOMBRE VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    --CAMPO IMAGEN VA UN ARCHIVO TIPO MULTIMEDIA
    --PERO PARA NO TENER PROBLEMAS A LA HORA DE 
    --LLENAR LAS TABLAS LE PUSE UN VARCHAR
    CATPR_IMAGEN VARCHAR (20),
    --ASIGNAMOS LA LLAVE PRIMARIA
    CONSTRAINT CATPR_ID_FK PRIMARY KEY (CATPR_ID)
);
```

**--CREACION DE LA TABLA PRODUCTOS**

```
CREATE TABLE FCT_PRODUCTOS (
    PRO_ID NUMERIC (5,0) NOT NULL,
    PRO_FECHA_ING DATE NOT NULL,
    PRO_NOMBRE VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRO_PRECIO_UNITARIO NUMERIC (5,2) NOT NULL,
    PRO_STOCK NUMERIC (5) NOT NULL,
    --"S" DISPONIBLE "N" NO DISPONIBLE
    PRO_ESTADO VARCHAR (1) NOT NULL,
    --CAMPO IMAGEN VA UN ARCHIVO TIPO MULTIMEDIA
    --PERO PARA NO TENER PROBLEMAS A LA HORA DE 
    --LLENAR LAS TABLAS LE PUSE UN VARCHAR
    PRO_IMAGEN VARCHAR (20),
    --ASIGNAMOS LA LLAVE PRIMARIA
    CONSTRAINT PRO_ID_FK PRIMARY KEY (PRO_ID)
);
```

**--CREACION DE LA TABLA FACTURA CABECERA**

```
CREATE TABLE FCT_FACTURA_CABECERAS (
    FACT_ID NUMERIC (5,0) NOT NULL,
    FACT_FECHA_EMISION DATE NOT NULL,
    FACT_SUBTOTAL NUMERIC (5,2) NOT NULL,
    FACT_IVA NUMERIC (4,2) NOT NULL,
    FACT_TOTAL_PAGAR NUMERIC (6,2) NOT NULL,
    --ASIGNAMOS LA LLAVE PRIMARIA
    CONSTRAINT FACT_ID_FK PRIMARY KEY (FACT_ID)
);
```

**--CREACION DE LA TABLA FACTURA DETTALLE**

```
CREATE TABLE FCT_FACTURA_DETALLE_PRODS (
    FDET_ID NUMERIC (5,0) NOT NULL,
    FDET_CANTIDAD NUMERIC (5) NOT NULL,
    FDET_PRECIO NUMERIC (5,2) NOT NULL,
    FDET_SUBTOTAL NUMERIC (5,2) NOT NULL,
    --ASIGNAMOS P.K
    CONSTRAINT FDET_ID_FK PRIMARY KEY (FDET_ID)
);
```

**--CREACION DE LA TABLA CLIENTE**

```
CREATE TABLE FCT_CLIENTES (
    CLI_ID NUMERIC(5,0) NOT NULL,
    CLI_FECHA_REGISTRO DATE NOT NULL,
    --ASIGNAMOS P.K
    CONSTRAINT CLI_ID_FK PRIMARY KEY (CLI_ID)
);
```

**--CREACION DE LA TABLA PERSONAS**

```
CREATE TABLE FCT_PERSONAS (
    PERS_ID NUMERIC (5,0) NOT NULL,
    PERS_FECHA_REGISTRO DATE NOT NULL,
    PERS_NOMBRE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PERS_APELLIDO VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PERS_CEDULA VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    PERS_CALLE_PRINC VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PERS_CALLE_SEC VARCHAR (50),
    PERS_NUMERO_CASA VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    PERS_TELEFONO VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    --ASIGNAMOS P.K
    CONSTRAINT PERS_ID_FK PRIMARY KEY (PERS_ID)

);
```

**--CLAVES FORANEAS**

```
ALTER TABLE FCT_CATEG_PRODUCTOS ADD CONSTRAINT CAT_PRO_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY(PRO_ID) REFERENCES FCT_PRODUCTOS(PRO_ID);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente fijate a que columna le estas diciendo que sea clave ajena de otra, en tu tabla `FCT_CATEG_PRODUCTOS` no hay una columna llamada `PRO_ID`, tienes que cambiarlo por `CATPR_ID` y funcionará:

```
ALTER TABLE FCT_CATEG_PRODUCTOS 
  ADD CONSTRAINT CAT_PRO_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY(CATPR_ID) 
    REFERENCES FCT_PRODUCTOS(PRO_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si uno o más productos están agrupados en una categoría 
tu DDL debería quedar así:

```
--CREACION DE LA TABLA Categ PRODUCTOS

CREATE TABLE FCT_CATEG_PRODUCTOS (
    CATPR_ID NUMERIC(5,0) NOT NULL,
    CATPR_NOMBRE VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    --CAMPO IMAGEN VA UN ARCHIVO TIPO MULTIMEDIA
    --PERO PARA NO TENER PROBLEMAS A LA HORA DE 
    --LLENAR LAS TABLAS LE PUSE UN VARCHAR
    CATPR_IMAGEN VARCHAR (20),
    --ASIGNAMOS LA LLAVE PRIMARIA
    CONSTRAINT CATPR_ID_FK PRIMARY KEY (CATPR_ID)
);
--CREACION DE LA TABLA PRODUCTOS

CREATE TABLE FCT_PRODUCTOS (
    PRO_ID NUMERIC (5,0) NOT NULL,
    PRO_FECHA_ING DATE NOT NULL,
    PRO_NOMBRE VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
-- ******* CAMPO QUE DEBES AGREGAR EN PRODUCTOS ***
    CATPR_ID    NUMERIC(5,0) NULL,
--- ***********************************************
    PRO_PRECIO_UNITARIO NUMERIC (5,2) NOT NULL,
    PRO_STOCK NUMERIC (5) NOT NULL,
    --"S" DISPONIBLE "N" NO DISPONIBLE
    PRO_ESTADO VARCHAR (1) NOT NULL,
    --CAMPO IMAGEN VA UN ARCHIVO TIPO MULTIMEDIA
    --PERO PARA NO TENER PROBLEMAS A LA HORA DE 
    --LLENAR LAS TABLAS LE PUSE UN VARCHAR
    PRO_IMAGEN VARCHAR (20),
    --ASIGNAMOS LA LLAVE PRIMARIA
    CONSTRAINT PRO_ID_FK PRIMARY KEY (PRO_ID)
);

--  LA LLAVE FORANEA DEBE QUEDAR ASI

ALTER TABLE FCT_PRODUCTOS ADD CONSTRAINT PRO_CAT_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY(CATPR_ID)
REFERENCES FCT_CATEG_PRODUCTOS(CATPR_ID)
```